# Finding the probability mass function in a balls and urns problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have $n$ balls and $m$ urns, and each ball is equiprobably distributed among the urns. Let $X$ be the random variable counting the number of empty baskets. What is the general probability mass function for $X$?

This problem is derived from solving an expected value problem. The expected value of empty urns is easily determined, from the linear properties of expected value. However, PMFs have no such nice properties, and it's not so obvious to me how I should approach this problem.

Comment: One cannot not get a "closed form," unless one allows the use of Stirling Numbers of the second kind. One can get a non-closed form by using Inclusion/Exclusion.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So this is definitely not an easy problem? Is there somewhere I can further read about this, then?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on Stirling numbers of the second kind may help. It is a not very hard problem. For the numerator, we want the number of ways we can have $k$ empty baskets. The baskets can be chosen in $\binom{m}{k}$ ways. Now we want to count the number of **onto** functions from a set of $n$ elements to a set of $m-k$ elements. That's where Inclusion/Exclusion or Stirling numbers come in. This question has been asked and answered on MSE a few times, at least once by me. But finding the questions/answers is not easy.